# How to get update notifications for the iq2oz site?

Tags: twitter, feeds, yahoo-pipes

This site [Intelligence Squared Australia - IQ2 - the Australian forum for live debate](http://www.iq2oz.com/) publishes past debates in pages like:

- [Past live debates: 2011 series Sydney](http://www.iq2oz.com/events/event-details/2011-series-sydney/index.php)
- [Past live debates: 2011 series Melbourne](http://www.iq2oz.com/events/event-details/2011-series-melbourne/index.php)

Not one of the pages have a RSS or ATOM feed. The only way to be notified is through Twitter? I don't have a Twitter account anymore and I don't want to use it directly. And the Twitter feed has many unwanted posts.

Should I make an Yahoo Pipe for each page and subscribe to the generated feed? How else can I be notified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created [the Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=681ac0be6da47bc2b51f686cacd10a5e) but it will work only for 2011 debates